# Hide-able views on the layout don't push other views after RecyclerView scrolled down and up again and the hide-able views set visible Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, layout, android-recyclerview

I currently develop an android app. Which is like a search engine. There are several predefined filters. I make those filters hidden whenever user clicks a button. And there is a RecyclerView which shows search results just under those filters. The layout is like in the picture:

[image]

Everything is normal till that point. But when I hide filters and scroll down the RecyclerView and scroll it up again and when I want to show the filters again they just go behind the RecyclerView. My layout code and the code that makes filters visible and gone are like those. Thanks in advance.

[image: after scroll down and up while filters are in gone state]

[image: after scroll down and up and making filters' visibility "gone" while filters are in visible state]

```html
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.SearchActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="200px"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout1"
    >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:id="@+id/resultCount" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="text"
            android:id="@+id/keywords"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="anahtar kelime(ler)"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resultCount"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keywords">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/lstSearchTypes"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20px"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"  />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                android:text="Ara"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20px"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
                android:backgroundTint="#ff00ff99"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEkFiltreler"
            android:text="Ek Filtreler"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".9"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll"
            android:visibility="visible"
      />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/lstDaireler"
                android:text="Daire"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".9"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnEkFiltreler"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:padding="20px"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"  />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/lstMahkemeler"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:text="Daire"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".9"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lstDaireler"
                android:padding="20px"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"  />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/lstBasliklikMi"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:text="Daire"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".9"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lstMahkemeler"
                android:padding="20px"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"  />
        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/sonIkiSenedekiKararlar"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".9"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lstBasliklikMi"
                android:text="Son 2 senedeki kararlar"
        />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvSearchResults"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".95"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sonIkiSenedekiKararlar"
            android:visibility="visible"            
            android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

```
 private void DoHideShow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dairelerSpinner.Visibility =
        mahkemelerSpinner.Visibility =
        sonIkiSenedekiKararlar.Visibility =
        baslikliMiSpinner.Visibility = dairelerSpinner.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone ? 
                        ViewStates.Visible :                                                                      
                        ViewStates.Gone;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this question , could you please post more details about this question,e.g. a simple demo or some other code snippet?

Comment: Hi Jessie, I don't think there is an option for uploading a video here. But I caught some useful information in recent trials. I realized that when I make the soft keyboard visible by calling showSoftInput method as the user hits the button for hiding/showing the filters, filter views can push my RecyclerView down as expected or don't leave empty space as in the 3rd screen shot. Maybe this information helps to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused with what you said.  When user click the button, why you make the soft keyboard visible? Could you please post a simple demo by uploading your code  and share a link here so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hi Jessie, I was just trying different things to see how the UI would react. I think that is not the point of my question though. Where can I prepare a demo page? Is there such an online service?

Comment: If it's convenient, you can upload your  demo here: https://github.com/     and share  your demo link here.

Comment: I can't share the codes since it is not a personel project. I found a workaround by using OnGlobalLayoutListener. Thanks for your interest Jessie

Comment: Congrats, happy coding.  :)